# CSS reactive design issue

Tags: css

I am making a reactive website; meaning it re-sizes with the window. It was going well until I hit the navigation bar, which has a 15px curve on the bottom left and right corners and has a width of 100%. I want to place two 20px divs i call `NavCap` on either side of the `Nav` (which acts as a wrapper) div. This is easy and allows me to space the buttons and add images the the ends. The middle section called `NavAction` will have a 1px repeating background image so that it loads super fast on cruddy server.

The problem is that `NavAction` needs to take up as much space as possible without pushing the right `NavCap` onto the next, hidden line. Here is my code:

```
#nav {    
   width: 100%;
   height: 55px;
   position: relative;
   bottom: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
   background-color: #020202;
   -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
   -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
   border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;    
}

#nav * {    
   box-sizing: border-box;
   height: 100%;    
}

#navCap {    
   width: 20px;
   height: 55px;
   float: left;
   background-color: blue;    
}

#navAction {    
   width: 97.91%;
   height: 55px;
   float: left;
   padding: 0;
   background-color: green;    
}

        <div id="nav">                
            <div id="navCap"></div>                
            <div id="navAction">

            </div>                
            <div id="navCap" class="right"></div>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't have two id's with the same value of `navCap`.

Instead of giving the `navAction` a width, give it a `left` and `right` value instead:

```
#navAction {
    position         : absolute;
    left             : 20px;
    right            : 20px;
    top              : 0;
    height           : 55px;
    background-color : green;
}
```

Then set your caps like so:

```
#navCapLeft, #navCapRight {
    width            : 20px;
    height           : 55px;
    position         : absolute;
    top              : 0;
    background-color : blue;
}
#navCapLeft {
    left : 0;
}
#navCapRight {
    right : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another simple solution:

```
<div id="nav">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>

#nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 55px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
    background-color: green;
}
#nav * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
}
.left,
.right {
    width: 20px;
    height: 55px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: blue;
}
.left {
    left: 0;
}

.right {
    right:0;
}
```